# Command line script to create user passwd

Tags: php, ubuntu, scripting, passwords

I'm very new to Linux and PHP so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I need to create a PHP command line script that will add a user to the system, to be used by the ftp server. I have it set up at this point that it creates the account just fine. The problem I'm facing is that even though I pass through the password when I create the account ie. -p $password, I still have to run the "passwd" command on the account and set the password manually before proftpd will let that account log in.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to run the passwd command from within the php. Obviously I can run it, but I have no idea how to programatically enter the password when prompted.

Just for more info, this is the command I run when creating the account. $username and $ password are passed into the function.

```
shell_exec("useradd ".$username." -g ftpusers -m -p ".$password." -d
/home/ftp/".$username."/ -s /bin/false);
```

now im looking to add something along the lines of:

```
shell_exec("passwd ".$username);
echo $password;
echo $password;
```

Just for the record, this last example is just for illustration.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the hashed password using useradd, e.g.

```
$password = escapeshellarg( crypt('password') );
shell_exec("useradd username -p $password");
```

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is
>   to disable the account.

([man useradd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd))

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick for me. I read about this "crypt" yesterday, I just couldn't get it to work.

hehe, anyways, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Can't guarantee it'll work, but on first thoughts, my solution would be:-

```
<?php
$fp = popen("/usr/bin/passwd " . $user, "w");

fwrite($fp, $password . "\n");
fwrite($fp, $password . "\n");

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', '')) {
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    ssh2_exec($connection, "useradd $username -m -p $password -d /home/$username/ -s /bin/false");
} else {
    die('Authentication Failed...');
}
```

Comment: Answers that just post some code without any explanation are generally not welcomed here ...